# Seaborn: Problem with values on the countplot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Gender":["Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female"],
                   "children":["0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1"]})
```

And I present this DataFrame on a seaborn countplot like this:
 `ax=sns.countplot(x="Gender", hue="children", data=df, palette="binary")`

I try to present values on each column on the countplot using this code:

```
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f'\n{p.get_height()}', (p.get_x()+0.2, p.get_height()), ha='center', va='top', color='white', size=18)
plt.show()
```

But I have Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'patches'
```

What can I do so as to have values on each column of the plot ? Please do not send my link to other answers I checked everything and I need simple answer. Please modyfi my code or tell me what is a reason of mentioned Error ? 
[image]

Comment: I could not reproduce your errror

Comment: I added this Error on similar example, what can I do ?

Comment: You're missing `set_title` in your question, can you add it back in?

Comment: Wow it works, thank you. And one more question which argument can I change in your code If I want to have values not inside columns but on the top of columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that `.set_title` returns text, not a matplotlib subplot.

You should instead do

```
ax=sns.countplot(x="Gender", hue="children", data=df, palette="binary")
ax.set_title(<insert your title here>)
```

on separate lines

Comment: Wow it works, thank you. And one more question which argument can I change in code If I want to have values not inside columns but on the top of columns ?

Comment: You'll want to change `p.get_height()` to `p.get_height()+.1` (I don't know what number you'll have to add, you might want to experiment a bit 'til you find one that looks good). Remember that you can upvote/accept an answer if you found it useful :)